# MySQL TIMEDIFF negative value

Tags: mysql

I've a problem using TIMEDIFF with two different date. The following query "should" return
00:04:51

```
mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF(TIME('2013-07-21 00:04:50'),TIME('2013-07-20 23:59:59'));
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+

|TIMEDIFF(TIME('2013-07-21 00:04:50'),TIME('2013-07-20 23:59:59')) |

+-------------------------------------------------------------------+

| -23:55:09                                                         |

+-------------------------------------------------------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any tips? Which is the easiest way?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TIME(TIMEDIFF('2013-07-21 00:04:50','2013-07-20 23:59:59'));
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+

|TIME(TIMEDIFF('2013-07-21 00:04:50','2013-07-20 23:59:59'))
```

Comment: `TIMEDIFF()` already returns a time. Wrapping it in `TIME()` does nothing.

Answer (score 5):

If there's no date info then it has to be assumed these values are on the same day. Retain the date info and it will work as expected*:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2013-07-21 00:04:50','2013-07-20 23:59:59');
```

**Provided the answer is smaller than TIMEs max of 838:59:59*

Answer (score 3):

That is a correct result, because you are casting your dates to only time values (you're stripping meaning part of your operands). If you want to include date influence to the result, you should use [DATE_DIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function or not to strip your dates by TIME() function.

Answer (score 2):

Don't convert your time stamp to using Time, just put your values like

```
TIMEDIFF('2013-07-21 00:04:50','2013-07-20 23:59:59')
```

.Check Further from Mysql Function [MysqlDate Time Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time)

B/c Time will extract only time from timestamp. so actually you are doing.

```
TIMEDIFF('00:04:50','23:59:59');
```

Answer (score 0):

To measure the distance simply evaluate whether the result is negative or positive and if negative, convert to positive:

```
SELECT IF( 
    TIMEDIFF( '2013-07-21 00:04:50', '2013-07-20 23:59:59' ) < 0,
    0-TIMEDIFF( '2013-07-21 00:04:50', '2013-07-20 23:59:59' ),
    TIMEDIFF( '2013-07-21 00:04:50', '2013-07-20 23:59:59' )
) AS distance_in_time
```

The `IF()` function allows us to return the negative inverse if the result is negative, or the result if the result is positive.